# SOAP request over HTTP delay

Tags: web-services, http, soapui

I am trying to send a SOAP request over HTTP for a web service through the following channels:

1. Telnet (HP-UX)
2. C client that opens a socket, writes XML and reads reasponse(HP-UX)
3. Perl client that does the same thing as the C client above(HP-UX)
4. Through SOAP UI application (http://www.soapui.org/)(Windows Machine)

While SOAP UI gets a response in about 100ms seconds or so; the rest of the channels get the same response but very slow.

I am wondering what might be the problem. If anybody has any idea about this please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the connection stays open per default for subsequent requests (not uncommon for webservers which expect you to request all kinds of javascript files, images, css files directly afterwards). You might want to try to send the `Connection: close` header.

Answer (score 0):

Check the protocol , may be you are using HTTP1.0 not HTTP1.1